# jqTransform id Selector does not work

Tags: jquery, html, selector, jqtransform

please see these html codes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="gmapkey" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="requiered/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js" ></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#abc').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
              });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form class="formTransform" action="post.php" method="POST">
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Input Text:</label><input type="text" name="inputtext"/></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Input Password:</label><input type="password" /></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Checkbox: </label><input type="checkbox" name="chbox" id=""></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Radio :</label> 
            <input type="radio" id="" name="question" value="oui" checked ><label>oui</label>
            <input type="radio" id="" name="question" value="non" ><label>non</label></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Textarea :</label> <textarea cols="40" rows="12" name="mytext"></textarea></div>

        <div class="rowElem">
            <label>Select :</label>
            <select name="select">
                <option value="">1&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="opt1">2&nbsp;</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <label>Select Redimentionné :</label>
            <select name="select2" >
                <option class ="abc" value="opt1">Big Option test line with more wordssss</option>
                <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="opt4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="opt5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="opt6">Option 6</option>
                <option value="opt7">Option 7</option>
                <option value="opt8">Option 8</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="rowElem"><label>Submit button:</label><input id="abc" type="submit" value="Envoyer" /></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Reset button:</label><input type="reset" value="Annuler" /></div>
        <div class="rowElem"><label>Input button:</label><input type="button" value="bouton" /></div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

why

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#abc').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
          });
```

does not work!
but this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.formTransform').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
          });
```

works!

what is the problem about that jquery selector?

thanks in advance

Comment: You're transforming two totally different things.

Comment: @BoltClock i just want to transform some buttons in my form, not all of them and that html codes are just for example for showing you the problem!

Comment: i am so carzy about that! why does not work?

Comment: i've dowloaded that plugin from here -> http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/  and those codes are for it's demo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code of the plugin, you must call jqTransform with a form not with your select.

BTW be aware that the plugin is: "Abandon project. Say farewell." (jcamenisch authored 7 months ago)
plugin code:

```
$.fn.jqTransform = function (options) {
var opt = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

/* each form */
return this.each(function () {
  var $form = $(this);
  if ($form.hasClass('jqtransformdone')) {
    return;
  }
  $form.addClass('jqtransformdone');

  $('input:submit, input:reset, input[type="button"]', this).jqTransInputButton();
```